# Downloading a small (vcf) file often fails on Android

Tags: android, download-manager

I have a web page where I can download a contact file (.vcf / vcard) to my Android phone and then open it to add to contacts.

The file is very small, only around 260-270 bytes.

On different versions of Android and different phones, the success rate of the download varies greatly.

On my Samsung Nexus S (ICS 4.0.4) using the stock browser and download manager, the download fails about 4 out of every 5 times.

If I look at DDMS locCat output I see

> 06-20 16:25:56.701: W/DownloadManager(6942): Aborting request for download 6728: Trying to resume a download that can't be resumed

On another Samsung Nexus S (ICS 4.0.4) it fails one out of 5 times.

When I download larger files, or apps, etc I don't see this problem.

Anyone have any idea why this download may fail so often?
Could it be related to the fact the file is so small?

MIME type is set to text/x-vcard

Comment: Can you paste the DDMS output - or any other error messages?

Comment: I got this when I tried just now      06-20 16:25:56.701: W/DownloadManager(6942): Aborting request for download 6728: Trying to resume a download that can't be resumed

Comment: What MIME type are you sending for the file? Is it text/x-vcard or something else?